# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop when defining multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I an defining 2 different and keep getting the error "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." When I change the index to another character the problem still persist. Any thoughts on how to solve this/

```
const navLinks = [
      {route: '/about', text: 'Works'},
      {route: '/products', text: 'Profile'},
      {route: '/contact', text: 'Contact'},
      {route: '/how', text: 'How'}
    ];

    const Links = navLinks.map((b, i) =>
      <Link key={i} to={b.route} activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} className="link is-info navbar-item is-hidden-tablet">{b.text}</Link>
    );

    const Links1 = navLinks.slice(0, 2).map((b, i) =>
      <p className="level-item has-text-centered is-hidden-touch">
        <Link to={b.route} activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} className="link is-info">{b.text}</Link>
      </p>
    );
```

Comment: You don't have property `key` in `p` tag in `Links1`

Comment: Facepalm, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be a missing `key` prop on paragraph elements in `Links1`. Try adding `key={ i }` to `<p/>` like so:

```
const Links1 = navLinks.slice(0, 2).map((b, i) =>
      <p key={ i } className="level-item has-text-centered is-hidden-touch">
        <Link to={b.route} activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} className="link is-info">
        {b.text}
        </Link>
      </p>
    );
```

Comment: Good looking out Dacre :)

Comment: @user992731 you're welcome - all the best with your project :-)

Comment: @user992731, if the answer helped you just consider accepting it :)